# VBA Returning the value selected by an option button

Tags: vba, radio-button, userform

I am working with a function to return the value selected by an option button from

https://www.engram9.info/excel-2003-vba/a-useful-but-not-so-simple-dynamic-userform-example.html.

However, it gives an error "Type Mismatch" not too far in.  I have stripped the code down a bit to simplify the question, hopefully leaving everything necessary to answer the question.

I have not been able to find the information needed.

```
    Function GetOption(OpArray, Default, Title)
        'https://www.engram9.info/excel-2003-vba/a-useful-but-not-so- 
         'simple-dynamic-userform-example.html
       Dim TempForm As Object
       Dim NewOptionButton As Msforms.OptionButton
       Dim MaxWidth As Long

       'Create the UserForm
       Set TempForm = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(3)

       TempForm.Properties("Width") = 800

       'Add the OptionButtons TopPos = 4
       MaxWidth = 0

       Set NewOptionButton = TempForm.Designer.Controls m
       'Type mis-match here

    End Function
```

Here is the calling sub:

```
    Sub TestGetOption()

       Dim Ops(1 To 5)
       Dim UserOption
       Ops(1) = "North"
       Ops(2) = "South"
       Ops(3) = "West"
       Ops(4) = "East"
       Ops(5) = "All Regions"

     UserOption = GetOption(Ops, 5, "Select a region")
     Debug.Print UserOption
     MsgBox Ops(UserOption)

     End Sub
```

Error message is "Type mis-match"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding a new option button, you'll need to use the Add method of the Controls object, and you'll need to provide the ProgID for the control...

```
Set NewOptionButton = TempForm.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.OptionButton.1")
```

For additional information, have a look at the following link...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/add-method-microsoft-forms